# Managing Emacs key-bindings in other applications?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, microsoft-windows

I'm relatively new to Emacs and like it a lot, especially the navigation commands such as: `C-e`, `C-a`, `C-f`, `M-f`, `C-n`, `C-p`, `etc.`

Unfortunately, I often find myself trying to use them in other applications like Microsoft Office, Internet Browsers, etc. without success.

The key bindings sometimes work, such as `C-e`, `C-a`, `C-n`, `C-p` while I'm writing in the Safari Browser on OSX. But most other applications don't do this and I find it quite perplexing.

It gets even more confusing if you are using several operating systems. In Microsoft Windows, the Control key is used for all standard commands, so `C-n` usually creates a new document or `C-p` for printing, while on OSX the `Alt` or `Cmd` key is blocked for those. So to get a consistent set of key bindings on Windows and OSX and Emacs seems very difficult without at least breaking the most basic standards of one of those operating systems.

**Q: How do you manage to do this on most operating systems?**

- Do you redefine key bindings also in other applications to match those of Emacs?
- Or do you redefine standard key bindings in Emacs to avoid conflicts with standard key bindings of the operating system?

Comment: One option: assimilate everything into Emacs. Use TeX/Markdown and EWW. Or, tweak your OS. On Windows you can use [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) to intercept and remap key strokes.

Comment: Regarding AutoHotkey, take a look at [emacs.ahk](https://github.com/usi3/emacs.ahk): "Allows you to use emacs-like key bindings on Windows environment".

Comment: thanks for those hints! However, I find it difficult to modify the system behavior that much, as it means that I would be totally lost on another computer running "Standard Windows" without my special configuration...

Comment: Martin: That tends to be the nature of using custom configurations. On Unix systems you can generally put all of your configuration files into version control, and can use that to (at least partially) recreate your environment on another machine. I don't know whether that's as easy to do on Windows, but if you find yourself having to use "Standard Windows" (or "standard" anything), you'll always have to accept that you don't have your customisations.

Comment: @Martin: You asked a question about getting Emacs keybindings in other programs, but then you say that you don't want to modify your system to become reliant on Emacs keybindings in other programs. Which is it?

Comment: It works in safari and a lot of text areas in Mac OS X because they are using the library readline, you can [check its manual to customize it through an init file] (http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9) system-wide. It is not a complete solution as it doesn't cover Windows though.

Comment: @Ryan: good point, you're right. Well, I would love to have the same keybindings I have got used to in Emacs also elsewhere. But I do not want to break general standard keybindings like "Ctrl-N" for creating a new file/item in MS Windows. I'd be interested how others solve this conflict and I'll edit the question accordingly..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Emacs. It is about doing some Emacs-like things in other applications.

Comment: For OSX settings pleas check this answer http://superuser.com/questions/1340224/how-to-enable-emacs-keybindings-on-macos-globally

Answer (score 2):

I see **different options** for solving this:

1. to "outsource" text editing to Emacs by copying the text into an Emacs buffer, edit it there and then copy it back to the original application.

   - There is e. g. the [It's all text extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) which makes that possible.
2. redefine the same keybindings like in Emacs in other Applications

   - as I wrote before, this seems to be nearly impossible in a multi-platform environment, where the Alt-Key is "blocked" by system wide commands in `MacOS X`, while the Ctrl-Key is blocked in the same way in `MS Windows`.
   - some of those `Emacs` navigation keybindings do already work in `Mac OS X`, e. g. in Safari in text fields, which is really cool. But then I try to use others (like M-f, M-b) which are already bound to system wide commands like Cmd-f for searching, and it fails...
   - for Firefox there is e. g. the [Firemacs](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/firemacs/en/) extension, which redefines the key bindings. I liked it a lot in the beginning, but then got really really confused and frustrated using other computers without this extension, so I disabled it.

Comment: Yet another option is to do about *everything* in Emacs.  I only use a browser and Emacs.  In Firefox I use Keysnail.js for Emacs keybindings.